# How to retrieve CodeSet.CodeSetType standard value set metadata xml file?

Tags: metadata-api, health-cloud

What are names for `StandardValueSet` files of the `CodeSet.CodeSetType` and `CodeSetBundle.Type` picklist fields?

I need to customize these picklist fields and save them to VCS to run deployments using CI/CD jobs.

Obviously, there is no such information on [StandardValueSet Names and Standard Picklist Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm) page.

By default, these fields provide only one "None" option.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Salesforce Support, they kindly provided an answer to the question above.

```
The StandardValueSet name for 'CodeSet.CodeSetType' is "CodeSetCodeSetType".
The StandardValueSet name for 'CodeSetBundle.Type' is "CSBundleUsageType".
```

[image]
[image]